# What is $gnu(18,480)\ $?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap, groups-enumeration

Probably, the number of groups of order $18,480$ can only be determined with GAP. But I may be wrong, so the question should not be understood to be purely computational. A better lower bound than my mentioned $1,005$ or a good upper bound would also be welcome.

I tried to determine the number of groups of order $18,480$ with GAP.

My GAP version once again failed because of a memory overflow.
 The final output :

```
#I     Iso: test isomorphism on groups of size 18480
gap: cannot extend the workspace any more!
gap: Press <Enter> to end program
```

> What is $gnu(18,480)$ ? Please approve with ForAll(x,IsGroup) , that the groups are actually non-isomorphic.
>
> What is the best upper bound, which can be determined without great effort ?

The calculation for  $9,240$ worked well and gives a lower bound for the desired value.

```
9240:779:[ [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 5, 1 ], [ 7, 1 ], [ 11, 1 ] ]:true
```

A better lower bound is $gnu(1,680)=1,005$.

Since the factorization of $\ \ 18,480=2^4\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\ \ $ has no large prime-power, there might be a method to determine the number of groups even without electronic help. Is someone has an idea, he/she is invited to show the method and the result.

Comment: How long did it take to run till the memory overflow?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov I would say 1-2 hours. I also have problems with the time-command. It should display the duration of the last calculation in milliseconds. Once I got a value much too low, and once even a negative value...

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov What do you think ? Is there any possibility to determine the number of gnu's of a given order WITHOUT storing the constructed groups ?

Comment: I suggest to always add even a rough estimate of time: knowing just whether it is measured in seconds/minutes/hours/days is helpful to the reader to decide when and where to try to run this calculation. The problem with time overflow after several hours of computation was reported before. It may be Windows Vista specific.

Comment: The memory overflow could be caused by the isomorphism check and not by storing all groups detected so far, though those of course contributed to memory usage. Regarding the other question, probably the algorithm does need to keep all groups discovered so far in memory, and can work in "small batches" (which could be also parallelised), but that requires reengineering of `ConstructAllGroups`.

Comment: By the way, it would be perfectly fine to report such cases as issues at https://github.com/alex-konovalov/gnu/issues instead of MSE. This will be useful for other potential contributors looking for feasible or challenging cases. Also, issues there are staying open until they are closed by the maintainers, while at MSE as soon as there are upvotes, the question would go "below the radar".

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Can I suggest a project such as "find prime factor of $2\uparrow \uparrow 4+3\uparrow\uparrow 4"$ in github ?

Comment: Hi Peter! Not sure - what does this notation mean, and what does "suggest a project" mean?

Comment: $2\uparrow \uparrow 4=2^{2^{2^2}}$. The same for $3\uparrow \uparrow 4$

Comment: I would like to invite people to search for a prime factor. There is no small factor, but the number is so big, that it should be composite.

Comment: In principle yes. If you have code for this problem that you want to share so maybe someone will improve it, or you have some notes with the background information to start with - why not. I suggest to look at [Ten Simple Rules for Taking Advantage of git and GitHub](http://dx.doi.org/10.1101/048744) to get an idea what it is useful for.

Comment: Regarding the notation - is it `((2^2)^2)^2` or `2^(2^(2^2))` ?

Comment: The convention is that power towers are calculated from above (from right, if the notation is linear). So, the number I am interested is $2\uparrow(2\uparrow(2\uparrow 2))+3\uparrow(3\uparrow(3\uparrow 3))$. Calculated from below (or from left) , the number would be small enough to completely factor it without any difficulty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$5397$ isomorphism classes of groups. About 5 hours, under 1 GB in (development version of) GAP.

Comment: Thanks. I've checked this with GAP 4.8.3, in 10 hours (perhaps on a slower machine).

Comment: Now added to https://github.com/alex-konovalov/gnu/blob/master/gnudata.g - there are already 10 precomputed values of $gnu(n)$ stored there.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Did you check with ForAll(x,IsGroup) ?

Comment: @Peter yes, there were no lists returned